# Redis pub/sub scalling, Socket.io on Node Js

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, publish-subscribe, socket.io-redis

I have developed multiplayer turn-based application on Node Js using socket.io and redis pub/sub.

Brief regarding my implementation are as follows:

Multiplayer turn-based game scaled over ALB using socket.io-redis adapter for redis pub-sub.

My concurrent user base is around ~0.4 Million so I need to scale redis pub-sub as that is a single node as well.

I went through below Links:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6G22a5Iooqk

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/B0_fvfDWLGM

Can anyone elaborate how should I proceed for this.

Comment: I have the same question and I don't know the answer but thank you for sharing the video.

Comment: do you have any idea regarding this @ipoteka

Comment: Did you find something ?